# How to apply the macro to multiple lines on Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to type " - updated" on these dates which are separated by a new line.
I have my macro on ALT + P.
I tried vertical select at the end of the date but the macro only applies on the first line. How do I apply the macro on multiple lines?

It works if I paste it but not when doing macro. It's a similar feature on VS code and EmEditor.

Start:

```
21 Mar-27 Mar
28 Mar-03 Apr
18 Apr-24 Apr
```

Result:

```
21 Mar-27 Mar - updated
28 Mar-03 Apr
18 Apr-24 Apr
```

Ideal result:

```
21 Mar-27 Mar - updated
28 Mar-03 Apr - updated
18 Apr-24 Apr - updated
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Notepad++ docs](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/) :

> Notepad++ is capable of recording some of your actions you perform while editing a document, and replaying those later on to avoid having to repeat that sequence of actions. This is called a macro and can save a great deal of time.

This means - Notepad++ Macros only playback ***your*** keyboard actions. You also need to know exactly where your cursor is.

- Set the cursor in line 1 to position 1
- Start the macro recording
- Go to the end of the line <kbd>End</kbd> and add the desired text
- Jump to the beginning of the line <kbd>Home</kbd>
- Go down one line
- Stop the macro recording

From the main menu execute *Macro > Run a Macro Multiple Times* and select Run until the end of file. This is resulting in:

[image]

In case you want to try it with RegEx you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)`
- Replace with: `$1 - update`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

```
(.+)
1st Capturing Group (.+)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times
```

[image]